# Calculate all possible connected planar graphs with "E" edge

Tags: recursion, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, graph-drawing, planar-graph

I'm developing a c++ program which calculate and draw all possible connected planar graphs with given E number edge. Like this :

My first thought was to find all possible solutions for the N edge by adding one edge to after finding the answer to (n-1) by doing **recursion**.
[image]

As you can see in the picture, the solution of the problem n = 4 is basically an improved version of the solution n = 3 with one edge more.

But it did not feel like a very effective solution. I could not find this problem in a  particular  algorithm.

is there any other way of finding and drawing all possible  connected planar graphs with E edge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any other way of finding and drawing all possible connected planar graphs with E edge?

Start with the complete graph K<sub>(E+1)</sub> - this will have `(E+1)` vertices and `E(E+1)/2` edges. Enumerate the edges `1 .. E(E+1)/2`.

- For each permutation of `E` values from the set `<1 .. E(E+1)/2>`

  - Keep those `E` edges and delete the rest
  - Delete any unconnected vertices
  - If the graph is connected, planar and is not isomorphic to a previous graph then

    - It is a new unique graph with E edges.

You can probably perform significant optimisations by considering the symmetry of the complete graph and eliminating permutations that have a combination of rotational and/or reflectional symmetry with a previous permutation.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you so much